# How to access beanstalk queue on multiple web servers

Tags: php, beanstalkd

I have installed beanstalk on one server.we have multiple production servers on which we want to use beanstalk. Currently only 1 web server has access to beanstalkd.

How to configure or use beanstalkd so that we can access the beanstalkd on all servers.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the specific issue is, but here's a generic check-list to ensure that the IP/Port is accessible from other machines

- Ensure Beanstalkd is on a public, routable IP address (not 127.0.0.1)
- open up any firewalls to enable the other machines to communicate with it
- test from the other machines you want to talk to Beanstalkd from

  - telnet 1.2.3.4 11300   (where 1.2.3.4 is the machine's IP address)

    > stats
    >
    > quit

Like any other service, your servers should be able to connect to the Beanstalkd by IP address from there. With the the [Pheanstalk](https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk) library, for example, the [first argument](https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk/blob/master/classes/Pheanstalk.php#L31) to to the constructor is the IP address of the server.